# how to delete a database row with angular and php?

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm building a project with angular and php. I have a html page that show list of customers from "Customers" table. i trying to delete a row by pressing a "delete" button, it doesn't delete and doesn't showing any errors. can anyone please help?

this is my code:

Controller:

```
  $scope.delete = function(deletingId, $index) {
        var params = $.param({"customer_id":deletingId});
        $http({
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
          url: 'http://localhost:8081/hamatkin/api/delete-customer.php/',
          method: "GET",
          data: params
        }).success(function(data){



          // var arr=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
          // console.log(data);
           var arr=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            $scope.customerDetails = arr;
             var arr2 = arr.split(",");
              arr2.splice($index, 1);


        });
      }
```

Php- delete-customer.php

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hamatkin");

  include_once 'Customer.php';
mysqli_query($connect,"SET character_set_client = utf8");
mysqli_query($connect,"SET character_set_connection = utf8");
mysqli_query($connect,"SET character_set_results = utf8");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$customer = new Customer();


if(isset($_GET['customer_id'])){
   $customer_id = $_GET['customer_id'];
   $del = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE customer_id='".$customer_id."'";
   mysql_query($connect, $del);
 }


$newURL = "/hamatkin/#/customerCards";
header('Location: '.$newURL);
?>
```

html

```
  <tr ng-repeat="x in customers  | filter:search_query | orderBy: order_query:reverse_query">

            <td>{{ x.customer_id}}</td>
            <td>{{ x.kind_Of_Customer}}</td>
            <td>{{ x.full_name}}</td>
            <td><a ng-click="delete(x.customer_id, $index)" class="btn btn-primary btn- active">מחיקה</td>
```

Comment: may i know why are you passing $index in ng-click="delete(x.customer_id, $index?

Comment: @vishal what are you suggesting to do?

Comment: want to understand why $index

Comment: in the controller   $scope.delete = function(deletingId, $index)

Comment: ok is your data is deleting from database?

Comment: no...the button doesn't work....it can't delete...and no errors in the console

Comment: is your id value coming in $scope.delete()?

Comment: yes, the value is coming from $scope.delete

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any errors ....I wish I did

Comment: $del = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE customer_id='".$customer_id."'"; after this just echo $del;

Comment: and copy that response and try to execute that query in your database and check it whether it is working or not

Comment: thanks vishal but still the same

Comment: are you getting value of $customer_id in your query?

Comment: make it correct mysql_query($connect, $del); to  mysqli_query($connect, $del);

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you're using `mysqli` to connect db, then you're using `mysql` for  execute query, you should use same lib, try to execute your query through `mysqli_query()`

Comment: thanks, i changed to  mysqli_query($connect, $del); but still the same

Comment: Do you browser send any request like `../delete-customer.php?customer_id=1`?

Comment: I don't know exactly what that means...can you be more specific what to do?

Comment: if the browser send request, it's ok with frontend, you should check your php code

Comment: push F12 on your browser, go to Network tab, it shows all requests that sends through page lifetime

Answer (score 0):

> try to understand the simple row deleting concept with angular

```
    <html ng-app="mainApp">
      <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         angular.module('mainApp').controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$http){
            //getting the table data from this http from database
               $http({
                  method : "GET",
                  url : "http://localhost/em/mod.php/info",
                  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                  }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                  $scope.mydata=response.data; 
                  }, function myError(response) {
                  $scope.mydata=response.statusText;
               });
                  $scope.delete=function(idd)
      {        

            //here delete passes the id to the php by which we will delete the row
            $http({
               method : "DELETE",
               url : "http://localhost/em/mod.php/info",
               data:{
               "id":idd,
               },
               headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
               }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                  $http({                 //here we are refreshing the table data
                     method : "GET",
                     url : "http://localhost/em/mod.php/info"
                     }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                     $scope.mydata=response.data;
                     }, function myError(response) {
                     $scope.mydata=response.statusText;
                  });
               }, function myError(response) {
               $scope.mydata=response.statusText;
            });
      }

      </script>
      //suppose we got the table data in $scope.mydata
      </head>
      <body  ng-controller="myCtrl">

         //Now below table we are showing our data and its id is passing in <a> delete when click press it send its id to the delete function 

          <table border="1">
               <tr>
                  <th>Predefine Message</th>
                  <th>CreatedBy</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Action</th>
               </tr>
               <tr ng-repeat="rs in mydata"> 
                  <td>
                     {{rs.message}}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     {{rs.createdby}}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     Active
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <a href="" ng-click="delete(rs.id)">Delete</a>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table> 



      </body>
   </html>
```